# expected value and variance proof

Tags: probability

Where am I going wrong? Trying to show that shows $E[(x-c)^2] = (\mu-c)^2 + \sigma^2$, where $E(x)=\mu$, and $Var(X)=\sigma^2$.
\begin{align}
Var(X) &= E[(X-\mu)^2]\\
Var(X) &= E(x^2) – [E(X)]^2\\
E [(X – c)^2 ] &= (\mu – c)^2 + \sigma^2\\
E(X^2) – 2cE(X) + c^2 &= \mu^2 – 2\mu c + c^2 + \sigma^2
\end{align}
$c^2$ cancels out
\begin{align}
E(X) (E(X) – 2c) &= \mu(\mu-2c) + \sigma^2\\
\text{if } E(X) &= \mu\\
\mu (\mu-2c) &= \mu(\mu-2c) + \sigma^2
\end{align}
$u(u-2c)$ cancels out

I'm not sure if I'm expanding wrong, but I suspect it has something to do with not replacing $\sigma^2$ with $Var(X)$. Any hints? I want to fix it on my own, but I'm a bit stuck....

Answer (score 1):

Try attacking it from the right-hand side instead. Expanding this
$$
\begin{align}
({\rm E}[X]-c)^2+\mathrm{Var}(X)&={\rm E}[X]^2+c^2-2c{\rm E}[X]+{\rm E}[X^2]-{\rm E}[X]^2\\
\end{align}
$$
from where we just need to let ${\rm E}[X]^2$ cancel out and use linearity of the expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\mathrm{Var}[x]=\mathrm{E}[x^2]-\mathrm{E}\left[x\right]^2
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\left[(x-c)^2\right]
&=\mathrm{E}\left[\color{#C00000}{x^2}-\color{#00A000}{2cx}+\color{#0000FF}{c^2}\right]\\
&=\color{#C00000}{\mathrm{Var}[x]+\mu^2}-\color{#00A000}{2c\mu}+\color{#0000FF}{c^2}\\[3pt]
&=\mathrm{Var}[x]+(\mu-c)^2
\end{align}
$$